# menus missing after suspend

Tags: 16.04, menu

So ever since the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 I have had this issue, when resuming from suspend my menus are missing. I then have to log out and sign back in for things to return to normal. This happens with all themes - default included. Thanks for your time and answers.

[[image: Menus missing after wake from suspend[1]]

Answer (score 0):

Graphics issue.  I have this problem on my system but I updated to the 4.7.4 mainline kernel and this fixed everything, most likely due to updated drivers.